# find().each() not finding anything

Tags: jquery, forms, find, each

I have this form:

```
<form method="post" action="#" data-action="ajax.php?method=create" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Name</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <input name="name" type="text" value="" class="form-control" required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Location</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <input name="location" type="text" value="" class="form-control" required>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I want to perform some basic validation on this form. However, my find().each() code doesn't work at all.

Here is that code:

```
$(document).on('submit', '[data-action]', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var form = $(this);

    // ensure required fields are filled in
    form.find('[required]').each(function() {
        alert('required field found');
    });
});
```

I am not getting any alerts even though the form clearly has 2 required inputs.

Why is this happening?

Comment: where is the submit button in your HTML?

Comment: Oops I forgot to add it in the question. But yes there IS a submit button in the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chromes built-in browser validation was stopping my code from executing. Adding `novalidate` to my form resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your submit button inside your form tags.  When that's done, your JQuery works.

Here is a link to a [Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/pa1nad0h/4/)

**HTML**

```
<form method="post" action="#" data-action="ajax.php?method=create" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Name</label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <input name="name" type="text" value="" class="form-control" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Location</label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <input name="location" type="text" value="" class="form-control" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).on('submit', '[data-action]', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  var form = $(this);
  console.log($(this));

  // ensure required fields are filled in
  form.find('[required]').each(function() {
    console.log('required field found');
  });
});
```

Comment: @kjdion84 - Yes, it does work.  You need to open Chrome Developer Tools (F12) and look at the console tab to see the results.  You'll see I replaced your "alert" with "console.log()", which is a less obtrusive way to handle debugging.